# mysql find rows with fractional part of number

Tags: mysql, floor

Using the MySQL command prompt, I want to SELECT all rows conataining a specific fractional part of number.

I have a field of type FLOAT called priority & I want to find all rows where the priority is X.2 where X can be any whole number.

Is there a way to use the MOD or FLOOR function to extract the ".2" in a query?

I've tried:

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE priority-FLOOR(priority) = .2 *(note the decimal point before the 2)*
```

but it returns empty set when I know there are at least 100 rows containing a priority of X.2

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the `LIKE` clause in MySQL?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE priority LIKE %.2%`

Comment: Yes I was stuck on this for a long time a while back and searched for weeks. It has something to do with the data type FLOAT (not exactly sure) and then one day out of desperateness I tried LIKE and it worked miraculously. :)

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are notoriously fickle to work with.  That is why SQL offers the `decimal` data type, which is fixed length.

Do what you want with between:

```
SELECT *
from table
WHERE priority-FLOOR(priority) between 0.15 and 0.25
```

Consider storing the priority as a decimal instead of a floating point number.

If you have "deeper" priorities, like 1.22 that you are trying to avoid, then do:

```
WHERE priority-FLOOR(priority) between 0.195 and 0.205
```

The range can be even narrower, if you need.